# Downloading Attachments over EWS API in C# is painfully slow - how to speed up?

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices

I'm using the EWS Managed API in C# to download a bunch of messages from my company's exchange server. Loading the messages themselves takes a long time considering that `service.FindItems()` only fetches limited information about the messages, but it's not a huge deal. The serious problem I'm facing is how long it takes to load attachments.

The program is supposed to display an email and its image attachment side-by-side. When loading a new email, it can take well over a minute for the attachment to load. I initially fetched the attachments for each message when the message was loaded, but I thought it would be better to try to load them all at once into a `List<EmailMessage>` so the program wouldn't have to fetch the attachments when loading individual messages.

Here's the code I used to do that:

```
        fetchView.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties);

        fetchView.Traversal = FolderTraversal.Deep;

        //create itemView for actual message query since we finally found the damn folder
        ItemView iView = new ItemView(int.MaxValue);

        FolderId sharedInboxFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, sharedMailbox);
        FolderId targetFolder = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Root, sharedMailbox);



        FindFoldersResults inboxFolders = service.FindFolders(sharedInboxFolder, fetchView);
        bool folderFound = false;

        //look through the folders in the inbox to find the user-specified one by name
        foreach(Folder f in inboxFolders)
        {
            if (f.DisplayName == Properties.Settings.Default.InboxFolder)
            {
                targetFolder = f.Id;
                folderFound = true;

            }
        }


        // Set itemview properties for FindItems() operation
        fullProperties.Add(ItemSchema.Body);
        fullProperties.Add(ItemSchema.Attachments);
        fullProperties.Add(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived);
        fullProperties.Add(ItemSchema.Subject);


        if (!folderFound)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Folder not found!");
        } else {

            SearchFilter greaterthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsGreaterThanOrEqualTo(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchDate);
            SearchFilter lessthanfilter = new SearchFilter.IsLessThan(ItemSchema.DateTimeReceived, searchDate.AddDays(1));
            SearchFilter dayFilter = new SearchFilter.SearchFilterCollection(LogicalOperator.And, greaterthanfilter, lessthanfilter);

            FindItemsResults<Item> fetchedMessages = service.FindItems(targetFolder, dayFilter, iView);

            foreach (Item i in fetchedMessages.Items)
            {
                EmailMessage msg = EmailMessage.Bind(service, i.Id, fullProperties);
                emails.Add(msg);
            }
        }
    }
```

I then save all the attachments to disk with

```
for (int i = 0; i < message.Attachments.Count; i++)
            {
                if (message.Attachments[i] is FileAttachment)
                {
                    FileAttachment att = message.Attachments[i] as FileAttachment;
                    att.Load();
                    using (FileStream attStream = new FileStream(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) + @"\Program\images\" + i.ToString(), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                    { 
                        att.Load(attStream);
                        attStream.Close();
                        attStream.Dispose();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Not FileAttachment!");
                }

            }
```

Then, to load an image and it's attachment, I do

```
imgViewer.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(/some/path/to/image/))
```

I suspect the hangup is during the save attachments phase. I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091745/exchange-web-services-attachment-load-is-slow) that indicated TraceFlags should be disabled, so I did `service.TraceFlags = TraceFlags.None` but that didn't seem to help at all. I'm contemplating just downloading all the attachments up front, or figuring out some kind of caching mechanism where I download the attachments of message[n+1...x] in the background while the user works on message[n], but this has limited usefulness, because the program should also let the user select an image and load it relatively instantly (i.e. much less than a minute).

Any suggestions are much appreciated.

Comment: `I suspect the hangup is during the save attachments phase.` When you profiled or debugged through it, where was it slow?

Comment: also, how many files approximatively do you attach, and which average size are they ?

Comment: @mjwills how would I see what code is running slow when debugging?

Comment: @Pac0 usually 2-3 attachments, I'd say around 1.5 mb on average but those are definitely variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loading the attachments twice for no apparent reason.
Remove the `att.Load();` from your `if (message.Attachments[i] is FileAttachment)` statement.

Maybe have a look at implementing [paging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/how-to-perform-paged-searches-by-using-ews-in-exchange) and in turn consider reducing your `ItemView` `pageSize` to batches of 1000 or less, instead of `MaxValue`

Also make sure you are only returning what you need in your [PropertySet](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/exchange-web-services/email-properties-and-elements-in-ews-in-exchange).
`BasePropertySet.FirstClassProperties` Consider changing this to just return what you need.

*Side Note:*
A good way to identify slow performing code is to use the .Net [Stopwatch](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch(v=vs.110).aspx) class.

```
Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
sw.Start();
// code
sw.Stop();
StopWatchLog stopWatchLog = new StopWatchLog();
stopWatchLog.CreateXMLTextFile("MethodName()" + " took" + sw.Elapsed.Seconds + " seconds.");
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I'll remove that line and if it's still slow, I'll try the stopwatch

Comment: So it looks like the issue is that .Load() is still making EWS calls, and can take up to 16 seconds to return 3 image attachments totalling ~4.5 mb. That's not an unreasonable amount of time for that call and file size, but my goal is to do 100% of the EWS calls up front and cache the attachments so that an employee using the program can start it in advance and then work quickly, even if startup takes 5 minutes. I thought adding `ItemSchema.Attachments` to my propertyset would cache the attachments locally so that I could access them without EWS calls later. That's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I've updated my answer with extra suggestions to possibly increase the performance. Sorry I'm not aware of any inbuilt attachment caching functionality. You might be able to write your own caching code which caches the attachments after you iterate through each batch (If you use paging).

Comment: @Nathan did this answer your question in the end? if so, please mark it as the answer, to help others who come across this question in the future